# Xdebug isn't showing php variable values or object structures in Netbeans

Tags: php, apache, netbeans, xampp, xdebug

I'm on a new box at work setting up my environment.  I configured netbeans like the instructions said [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug).  I've done this before.  It was rather straight forward last time and worked the first time (a rare treat in programing).  However, when I run xdebug in netbeans I can't view variable values or object structures.  Here is a screen shot.

[Netbeans Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPjx2.jpg)

There should be more information.  I can print the `$model` variable to the screen.  It has array values and other information.

NetBeans IDE 6.9.1

xdebug 2.1.1

xampp 1.74

Comment: I know I've seen this... I _think_ it was a version mismatch between xdebug and php

Comment: Hoping somebody can provide a solution that doesn't include installing WAMP.  Getting the same behavior in Netbeans 7.0 on Windows 7 with XDebug 2.1.1.  I installed LAMP components separately so this is not a XAMPP issue specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problems with xDebug and the current Eclipse PDT under Windows 7 and was unfortunately unable to resolve them.

I finally switched to the [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) distribution where the same configuration seems to work.

Comment: Yeah, I had it working before I got a new box.  Windows xp, netbeans and xdebug.  Now, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a reinstall of my wamp environment.  I grabbed the newest xampp and used the xdebug dll it came with. It now works.  I'm guessing this was a PHP/xdebug version mismatch.